# Cannot create service references in visual studio 2012 - Cannot find DataServicesClientGererator

Tags: visual-studio, service-reference

Recently, when I attempt to add a service reference from our Sharepoint site to *any* WPF application, I get an error message.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express for desktop applications. To add the service reference, I go to *Project>Add Service Reference*, selected the service URI and clicked "Ok."

I immediately get the following error:

*"Cannot find custom tool 'DataServicesCoreClientGenerator' on this system."*

I have added this same service reference to other WPF applications without problems in the past, however I can no longer add service references to any current or new application, including applications that I have added service references to in the past.

I don't understand the error as this is not a "custom tool." I reinstalled Visual Studio, but continue to receive the same error.

Comment: Has anyone not experienced this problem and found a solution? After seven days I'm still no closer to solving this.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by installing [WCF Data Services 5.3.0 RTM Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35840).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Seriously, I could hug you. Not sure how the WCF tools were uninstalled, but my problem is fixed so I'm happy.

Comment: This did not fix my issue. After installing WCF Data Services 5.3.0 RTM Tools I am still getting the same error.